# How to make the navbar dropdown list display horizontally, center aligned when screen size is bigger than breakpoint for collapse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

All the code in question is found at https://codepen.io/taniarascia/pen/dYvvYv

This is responsive nav bar without bootstrap.

I want to manipulate how the dropdown shows when the screen size is larger than the break point. I want it to diplay horizontally, and center aligned. I understand using @media to detect the screen size, but then what css can be used to display it horizontally centered?

```
<ul class="nav-dropdown">
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Web Design</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Web Development</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Graphic Design</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

I think the css that would be edited is

```
.nav-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

but I'm at a loss on how to edit it for the view I want.

I'm adding a picture. I want the dropdown horizontal, not a vertical stack.
[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand the question - when you say centrally aligned, do you mean the dropdown should appear in the middle of the screen rather than under the main menu item?

Comment: sorry if I'm not clear. I want the dropdown content to be horizontal across the page, rather than vertically stacked

Answer (score 0):

Go to line 45 of your CSS and comment out one part:

```
 //position: relative;
```

Apparently setting the position of li elements drastically changes the way they behave. Didn't know that one.
As to centering them in against parent **li** node, this requires quite a lot of JS to make it work, as you would have to calculate the number of elements and apply negative left margin to child **ul** node. Think twice before doing so as it increases the complexity of your solution in drastic way.

DEMO: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pWaOYP

Comment: I added a picture of the element I'm talking about. I want that to spread out horizontally versus the vertical stack you see in picture.